# How to structure a database for a survey application?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a small survey application in Laravel and I'm not sure how to structure the database. There are three main entities for it:

- Users
- Surveys
- Questions

A user can fill in many surveys and a survey can have many questions. For this I'm creating two pivot tables:

- user_survey (id, user_id, survey_id)
- survey_question (id, survey_id, question_id)

But I'm not sure how to store answers as a user may also fill out the same survey multiple times so there needs to a way differentiating between different versions of a users answers.

My thought at them moment would be to create an additional table called user_survey_answers with the following columns:

- id
- survey_instance_id (will reference the id column from the user_client table)
- question_id
- question_answer

Would this be the best structure to use for this? If so, how would I create the eloquent relationships within Laravel to reference the user_survey_answers table?

Comment: Exact same thing as I was going to type lol  Table for the questions based on question id, table for user answers based on an id but also a session id for that user.

Comment: imagine it was a shopping site, where users could place orders. So, you'd have a table for users, a table for orders (which user placed which order), and a table of order details (what exactly each order consists of). Does that help? Incidentally, the surrogate ids in your 'pivot' tables are redundant